# How to secure dual-homed Windows Servers that are connected to the internet

Tags: windows, networking, sql-server

We have two machines running windows server 2012. Both have one NIC port connected to the public internet and another NIC port connected to a switch with internal IPs (192.168...).

What is the most secure way to connect the two machines to share files, services (SQL server), but not be accessible from the outside? (What windows settings should we enable/disable?)

Comment: Why are they connected with a NIC to the public internet? Why don't you use a single NIC and port forward whatever public traffic you need to the private NIC?

Answer (score 0):

The most secure method would be to not connect them directly to the internet at all.

You can use a firewall (either external or the system's), only allowing the ports strictly needed to be accessed by the public internet access through the firewall.  Set the default to Deny on the public-facing ports.